# Enabling EFS on FileStream Folders

Tags: filesystems, encryption, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2014

Please help me on below:

Below is my Environment:

Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

SQL Server 2014 SP2 GDR

Availability Groups 2014 with 3 Node (2 Sync and 1 BCP async)

I have 7 Databases with FileStream enabled.

Each 7 DB Filestream data folders is around 500 GB.

Due to security policy I need to enable both Transparent Data Encryption (TDE for structured data) and Encrypting File System (EFS on FileStream folders).

**All the EFS related pre-work like creation of Data Recovery Agent (DRA) and EFS Certificate enrollment completed in Windows Server and at AD Level.**

While enabling EFS on FileStream folders I am getting below error.

(NOTE : I am doing it by turning the SQL Servers offline and before taking services offline , I am failing over AG to next available Synchronized AG Node)

[image]

I cannot Ignore the error and move on , because of which please advise on below:

I even tried turn off anti virus and Firewall , still no luck

1. What is the root cause of this issue and how can I perfectly enable EFS for the 7 DBs FS Folders .
2. Can I try enabling the EFS on multiple DB FS Folders keeping in mind their sizes (500 GB each) ?

Kindly advise. Thanks

Comment: Have you created the certificate, and imported that certificate into the certificate store, that will be used to encrypt the files?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound , yes I did that and edited question too . Thanks

Comment: Find out which process is using the file, using Process Explorer, then stop it.

Comment: Are you willing to consider a third party product?